# Unable to Connect to GitHub.com For Cloning in ffmpeg installation

Tags: php, git, github, ffmpeg

I am trying to clone the **Yasm**  git repository

**Command:-** `git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/yasm/yasm.git` ,

but i am getting the following message when i enter the above command

**Error:-**

```
Cloning into 'yasm'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out
```

I am installing YASM for ffmpeg installation in **centos6.x**.

FFMPEG installation link: [Ffmpeg installation link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos#FFmpeg)

Any ideas what the problem is?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning works for me.  And pinging 192.30.252.131 works too.

Maybe it's a transient problem?

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: It means that it was a connection issue between your machine and GitHub's servers.